# Call function at every perticular time interval in android jni code

Tags: android, c, linux, timer, java-native-interface

When my android application get started i need to call one function routine at every fixed time interval lets say 50ms.

so i need to call that function routine called at every 50ms.

So is it possible in pure `C jni` code? Is there anything available in android stack? any `software` or `hardware timer` or `clock function`?

Comment: Why don't you use Handler?

Comment: It's Java code not C. Do you have to use C code?

Comment: yes need to do in c code only